# Tenant lost the job because of covid-19 and unable to pay the rent. Now what?

Tags: tenant, illinois, covid-19

I own a condo apartment in Schaumburg Illinois. The tenant has lost her job because of COVID-2019 and is unable to pay the rent. I however have to pay the monthly installments as mortgage for this house.

What are the options for me? Can i terminate the lease which currently ends on October 2020? Is there a law where i can evict the tenant?

Comment: Is your tenant eligible for any kind of unemployment benefit?  If so, why are they unable to pay the rent?  And if not, why would you kick them out of their home, when they already can't buy food and other essentials?

Comment: @DawoodibnKareem - I have to pay my mortgage too. Bank doesnt forgive my monthly isntallment so sorry i am not doing charities

Comment: Sure, but what happens if you DO evict your tenant? That's not going to make it easier to pay your mortgage.

Comment: That is out of scope for this question

Comment: I'd first like to clarify the statement *'I own a condo apartment'*, which in my mind is less of *own* and more of the bank owns. Let us know the risk management strategies that you had in place prior to the Covid-19 outbreak. Even though the economic environment is extremely different now, your already in place strategies (or lack of them) can give insight into how you might propose to handle this situation. Evicting the tenant gives you no net benefit until you can get a new tenant. Plus you're also stuck with the potential legalities of lawsuits and emergency government rulings. I would exp

Comment: The tenant has a history of not paying a single rent without multiple followups including not paying late fees for last few months. I dont want covid to be an excuse for not paying the rents anymore. Thats why i kept only eviction as the scope of this question, I have discussion going on with my attorney regarding this too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Any eviction order (for non-payment) [will not be enforced](https://www.cookcountysheriff.org/swap-precautions/) by the sheriff ([as ordered by the court](https://www.cookcountysheriff.org/wp-content/uploads/2020/03/GAO2020-01.pdf)), and that is how evictions would happen. This is also required under the governor's [order of March 20](https://www2.illinois.gov/Pages/Executive-Orders/ExecutiveOrder2020-10.aspx). Foreclosure entails eviction – though the order prohibits the enforcement of an associated eviction order, and doesn't prohibit starting action against a property owner. Theoretically, you could file for eviction against your tenant and at some point the petition could be granted, and the sheriff would enforce it. Those are the current legal options. Current (optimistic) projections are that evictions could happen in the second half of May.

Comment: Are there any things in place to protect landlords in this time, or are they basically being told to eat the cost of a non-paying tenant?

Comment: @Moo Well the governor's order specifically states that it does not relieve any party of their obligation to pay rent, mortgage, etc.  It's just that the state will not enforce eviction orders.  So the tenant still owes that rent as specified in their rental agreement, and could be pursued for it (though I do not know if such action has to be delayed until the end of the order or not, etc.).  Makes one wonder how things are going to go down when the order ceases and lots of people have unpaid rent and still no job. There are probably tax deductions, too.

Comment: @user6726 - Are people who lost their job because of covid going to get any unemployment benefits to pay their rent?

Comment: Unemployment benefits certainly have not been *suspended* because of the virus, though it may be hard to actually collect, given the demand on the system.

Comment: @user979189 unemployment benefits are typically available to anyone who loses a job involuntarily.